# Do not login user after registering if user already logged in

Tags: php, laravel

Yes, you read that right. Let me explain. I am using the default authentication process that comes with laravel 5.4, and am looking to allow admin users the ability to register new users. I have modified the middleware `RedirectIfNotAuthenicated` to allow access to `/register` if the user who is logged in is admin (in my case that means they have a type of '1'):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

        if(!Auth::user()->type == '1'){
            return redirect('/');
        }

    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

My question now becomes, how within the existing `RegisterController` do I NOT log the user in upon successful registration if the account is being created by an admin. Obviously this will involve a check to see if the user is currently logged in and an admin, but where I'm hung is after that block, as to me it looks like something that is being done elsewhere?

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

    if(isset($data["director"])){
        $this->redirectTo = '/organizations/create';
    }

    if(Auth::user()->type == '1'){

        //create the user and not log them in

    } else {

        return User::create([
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't actually need to use the RegisterController shipped with Laravel, to create users as admin. In whatever the AdminController you use, you can have the following code to create a new user with proper validation of cause:

```
User::create([
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
```

You just need to persist the user data in the respective tables and once the user logs in from frontend LoginController will handle the rest.

Also, RegisterController shipped with Laravel uses RegistersUsers Trait, which has the additional functionality you noticed in the controller.

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php
```

Comment: This does appear to be the best way to handle the situation. I added logic to the default register view that checks if user is guest or admin so that it can be reused with a separate admin controller (if admin post to a different route). My main concern was maintaining the same form in two separate locations.